# Cumulative charts within Webdesign

Tags: websites, chart

A rather simple question here, With regards to web design and the paperwork behind it (Which I am sure many people/companies don't actually do).

Would there be any reason for using a Cumulative Chart? 
Specifically a Cumulative Resource chart, although I am unsure what the resources could even be!

More to the point, there are a few ideas I have been thinking of, unsure of whether they are valid or not I have come to the guys behind programming a website!

tl;dr :

If it is possible, what can I make a cumulative resource chart for in relation to a website?

Comment: Can you explain the relationships in the chart. What are the dependent and independent variables?